# Explicitly specify linefeed character and not carriage return

Tags: xslt

I'm having trouble generating text files in the format required by a clients interface. The clients requires Linefeed characters at the end of every line in the file.

I'm using Microsoft XSLT processor and seem unable to specify a linefeed character. Here's some examples I've created trying to address the issue.

**XSLT**

```
<xsl:output method="text"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:text>LINEFEED</xsl:text>
    <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:text>CARRIAGE RETURN</xsl:text>
    <xsl:text>&#xD;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:text>LINEFEED + CARRIAGE RETURN</xsl:text>
    <xsl:text>&#xA;&#xD;</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>
```

**Output**

EFBB BF4C 494E 4546 4545 4420 7841 **0D0A** 4341 5252 4941 4745 2052 4554 5552 4E20 7844 **0D0A** 4C49 4E45 4645 4544 202B 2043 4152 5249 4147 4520 5245 5455 524E **0D0A 0D0A**

At present I am unable to find a way of explicitly just outputting a linefeed character (0A).

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Microsoft has lots of XSLT processors, there are MSXML 3, MSXML 4, MSXML 5, MSXML 6 in the COM world and XslCompiledTransform and XslTransform in the .NET world. Which one exactly do you use, how exactly do you run the transformation?

Comment: Are you using notepad to open your .txt file?

Comment: It took a bit of searching through source code but we're using XslCompiledTransform.

Comment: @FailedDev No I'm not opening it in notepad or any other application before I'm investigating it in a HEX editor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**In case you are using .NET XslCompiledTransform you can use an XmlWriter and specify the [XmlWriterSettings.NewLineChars](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlwritersettings.newlinechars.aspx) Property in the desired way**.

Comment: Had to do a bit of digging through Source Code but we are indeed using XslCompiledTransform. We are however using a StringWriter to create the output. Now I'm going to have to raise Change requests for the relevant libraries but thanks for pointing me in the right direction.